# How to read value of a textbox while typing inside textbox in Angular 6 (Reactive form)

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have textbox in a reactive form in Angular 6 and I want to read the value of the textbox field immediately when I am typing inside the textbox (rather than while on blur out of that textbox.).

ValueChanges event is happening only when I blur out of this textbox.

My intention is to get the value of textbox while I am typing inside textbox.

**component.html**

```html
<kendo-autocomplete formControlName="requestedFor" class="form-control" placeholder="Type User" style="height:3.25rem" [data]="this.userNames" 
                        (keydown)="this.searchUsersDetails()"  required >
</kendo-autocomplete>
```

**component.ts**

```js
searchUsersDetails() {
    console.log('Onkey up');
    console.log('control value::: ' + this.requestForm.controls.requestedFor.value);
    this.requestForm.controls.requestedFor.valueChanges.subscribe(
    term => {
      if (term !== '') {
          console.log('term::' + term);
        this.dataService.searchUsers(term).subscribe(
          data => {
              this.userDetails = data;
              const userNamesTmp = new Array(this.userDetails.length);
              this.userDetails.forEach(function (userDetailTmp) {
                  userNamesTmp.push(userDetailTmp.name);
              });
              this.userNames = userNamesTmp;
          });
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Was my answer useful in some ways?

Answer (score 0):

```
(keydown)="this.searchUsersDetails()"
```

---

```
searchUsersDetails() {
   ...
   this.requestForm.controls.requestedFor.valueChanges.subscribe(...)
```

Just... no.

Subscribe to the `valueChanges` `Observable<any>` via `OnInit` (`ngOnInit` method)

```
this.requestForm.controls.requestedFor
                         .valueChanges
                         .pipe(startWith(undefined))
                         .subscribe(v => ...)
```

Comment: @VaibhavBhardwaj It means that the first emitted value is always undefined. I use it to be sure at least one value is emitted.